# Why did the Drakh put the Keeper on Sheridan and Delenn's child, not Sheridan and Delenn themselves?

Tags: babylon-5

In the episode *Objects at Rest*, Londo gives Sheridan and Delenn a trophy, containing a gift to "*give to your children when they turn 16*", which contains a Keeper to control their children.

Why wouldn't they instead try to take over Sheridan and Delenn?  They could try to start undermining the Alliance beforehand, and they could always have Sheridan and Delenn give their Keepers to their children (or just get another one).

Comment: Sheridan is protected by Vorloon Voodoo (making him a poor candidate) and presumably he would also notice if Delenn's personality changed, and might do something about it. By comparison, a change in perspective from a young adult would be unremarkable.

Comment: Trying to remember if this was elaborated on in the Centauri Prime novel trilogy, but its been so long since I read it.

Comment: @suchiuomizu - Not directly, but the limits of keepers are gone into more... I'm dredging memory for answers now.

Comment: Sheridan's mid has come into contact with a Vorlon mind so that it might give him protection or the ability to sense if a keeper is being placed on him

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Implanting a Keeper on David is more likely to succeed, and gets them all three.**

The Keepers aren't complete puppeteer parasites, although the show doesn't go out of it's way to dispel that illusion.

- Londo volunteered for his Keeper, after the Drakh had showed their hand and threatened Centauri Prime unless he cooperated.
- The Regent apparently had his implanted in his sleep, and it inevitably broke his mind, to the point where he was virtually in hiding.
- The *Legions of Fire* trilogy of novels goes into more detail about what they can and can not do.  Influence the mind, yes.  Control the mind, only with extreme difficulty.  Report on everything the bearer does and senses, yes.  Inflict indescribable pain, yes.  Londo tests this last at one point, and is left wetting himself insensate on the floor, after what he is later told was only a few seconds.

David grows up with the Keeper nearby.  It is able to plant it's influence long before it actually attaches, such that it matters a lot less if he has his own strong personality to resist for a time.  Sheridan and Delenn are both strong-willed people that would die before harming their loved ones, or do more than token actions to subvert the Alliance they built.  They would however follow David into a supernova, neatly delivering all three to the Drakh to fulfill their revenge.